# Sunburst D3 partition and external .csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a sunburst d3 partition that works very fine with text data directly on the .js file. Now I want to load/read and external .csv file so that each time my data changes it will reflect on the chart.

Here is my .js file:

```
// Dimensions of sunburst.
var width = 950;
var height = 750;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

// Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
var b = {
  w: 150, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
};

// Mapping of step names to colors.
var colors = {
  "1": "#766A62",
  "Vehicle Downtime": "#766A62",
  "Vehicle Downtime": "#766A62",
  "Vehicle Downtime": "#766A62",
  "Vehicle Downtime": "#766A62",
  "Vehicle Downtime": "#766A62",
  "2": "#EAAB00",
  "4": "#8E9300",
  "5": "#006983",
  "TARGET MET": "#6ab975",
  "TARGET NOT MET": "#f03e33",
};

// Total size of all segments; we set this later, after loading the data.
var totalSize = 0;

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

// Use d3.text and d3.csv.parseRows so that we do not need to have a header
// row, and can receive the csv as an array of arrays.

d3.text("mypizza.csv", function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
  createVisualization(json);
});


/*var text =

"1-Actual spending/budget x 100-Financial Management Cost Control-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
2-Number of Health & Safety issues addressed/Number of Health & Safety issues reported-Address Health & Safety Issues-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
4-Number of hours of training-Staff Training & Development-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
5-As per plan-Going Regional-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
1-Number of days in operational-Vehicle Downtime-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
2-Budget/Time-Investing in Science & in our Future-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
4-number of staff-Staff Training & Development-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
5-Organise one (1) outreach programme annually-Collaboration with other government agencies-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
1-Number of days in operational-Generator downtime-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
2-Budget variation-Investment-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
4-Number of hours of training-Attract and retain staff-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Current projects runing at the field station-Attract Scientific Projects to Basse Field Station-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
2-Organise at least one HSE awareness programme at each field station before the end of the year-Maintain staff interest in HSE-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
4-Number of hours of training-People-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
1-Availability of electricity-Value for money-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
2-Develop occupational risks register and communicate to staff members before commencement of their duties and updated versions communicated to old staff members annually-Occupational risks management-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
4-As per HSE plan-Knowledge in HSE-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Streaming IT procurement-Value for money-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
2-50% workforce participation-MRC & Me-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET,1\n\
4-90% starters complete module 1-eLearning induction-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Non availability of water-Value for money-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
2-No disputes-Employee relations-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
4-90% compliance-Performance Development Review-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Timely completion of Work Requests-Value for money-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
2-Security audit-Information Security-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
4-As per plan-Training staff in Quality Related Matters and Enhance the concept of Quality-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Budget variation-Cost Control-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
2-Train IT staff, a professional certificate per staff per year-Attract and retain staff-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Have a system in place to manage waste production; and chemical use in the laboratories-Improving efficiency-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
2-As per plan-Retaining GCLP Accreditation-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
2-As per plan-Maintain applicable Quality Standards-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Full implementation by January 2016-Attract & retain staff-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
2-As per audits-Improve on Applicable Quality Standards-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-% recovery-Value for Money-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Content management and collaborating systems, implement one new productivity suite-Productivity-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Monitor help desk metrics-Reliable and enabling IT platform-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Install and monitor systems at identified facilities-Invest in more electronic access control Systems-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Install & implement a Visitor management systems-Acquire a visitor management system-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-Quarterly meetings with G4S operations manager-Managing the security contract-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
1-BCT Meetings and Drills/Exercises-Emergency Preparedness Planning – General & site specific -TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET-TARGET MET-TARGET NOT MET,1\n\
";
*/

  //var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
//  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
//  createVisualization(json);


// Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
function createVisualization(json) {

  // Basic setup of page elements.
  initializeBreadcrumbTrail();
  drawLegend();
  d3.select("#togglelegend").on("click", toggleLegend);

  // Bounding circle underneath the sunburst, to make it easier to detect
  // when the mouse leaves the parent g.
  vis.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", radius)
      .style("opacity", 0);

  // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
  var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      });

  var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      //.style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; })
      .style("fill", function(d) {return d.depth==2 ? colors[d.parent.name] : colors[d.name];})
      //.style("fill", function(d) { if(d.depth!=2) {return colors[d.name];} else {return colors[d.parent.name];} })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover);

  // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
  d3.select("#container").on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

  // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
  totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
 };

// Fade all but the current sequence, and show it in the breadcrumb trail.
function mouseover(d) {
  if (d.depth > 3) {
    var mission = "MISSION: " + getAncestors(d)[0].name;
    var kpi = "KPI: " + getAncestors(d)[1].name;
    var goal = "GOAL: " + getAncestors(d)[2].name;
    //console.log(kpi);
    var yesno = "";
    if (d.name === "TARGET MET") {
        yesno = "Q" + (d.depth - 3) + ": " + "Target met";
    }
    else {
        yesno = "Q" + (d.depth - 3) + ": " + "Target not met";
    }
  }
  else if (d.depth === 3) {
    mission = "MISSION: " + getAncestors(d)[0].name;
    kpi = "KPI: " + getAncestors(d)[1].name;
    goal = "GOAL: " + getAncestors(d)[2].name;
  }
  else if (d.depth === 1) {
    mission = "MISSION: " + d.name;
  }
  else {
    //mission = Math.round((d.value/totalSize)*100)+"%";
    mission = "MISSION: " + getAncestors(d)[0].name;
    mission = "ME: " + d.name;
    //kpi = "KPI: " + getAncestors(d)[1].name;
    //goal = "GOAL: " + getAncestors(d)[2].name;
  }
  var percentageString = mission + "\n" + kpi + "\n" + goal;
  d3.select("#percentage")
      .text(mission);
  d3.select("#percentage2")
      .text(goal);
  d3.select("#percentage3")
      .text(yesno);
  d3.select("#percentage4")
      .text(kpi);

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .style("visibility", "");

  var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);
  updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);

  // Fade all the segments.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .style("opacity", 0.3);

  // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
                return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
              })
      .style("opacity", 1);
}

// Restore everything to full opacity when moving off the visualization.
function mouseleave(d) {

  // Hide the breadcrumb trail
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "hidden");

  // Deactivate all segments during transition.
  d3.selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);

  // Transition each segment to full opacity and then reactivate it.
  d3.selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .each("end", function() {
              d3.select(this).on("mouseover", mouseover);
            });

  d3.select("#explanation")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style("visibility", "hidden");
}

// Given a node in a partition layout, return an array of all of its ancestor
// nodes, highest first, but excluding the root.
function getAncestors(node) {
  var path = [];
  var current = node;
  while (current.parent) {
    path.unshift(current);
    current = current.parent;
  }
  return path;
}

function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select("#sequence").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
}

// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var g = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

  entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .style("fill", function(d) { if(d.depth!=2) {return colors[d.name];} else {return colors[d.parent.name];} })


  entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
  g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });

  // Remove exiting nodes.
  g.exit().remove();

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percentageString);

  // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");

}

function drawLegend() {

  // Dimensions of legend item: width, height, spacing, radius of rounded rect.
  var li = {
    w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, r: 3
  };

  var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", d3.keys(colors).length * (li.h + li.s));

  var g = legend.selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.entries(colors))
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
              return "translate(0," + i * (li.h + li.s) + ")";
           });

  g.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("rx", li.r)
      .attr("ry", li.r)
      .attr("width", li.w)
      .attr("height", li.h)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.value; });

  g.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", li.w / 2)
      .attr("y", li.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
}
function toggleLegend() {
  var legend = d3.select("#legend");
  if (legend.style("visibility") == "hidden") {
    legend.style("visibility", "");
  } else {
    legend.style("visibility", "hidden");
  }
}
// Take a 2-column CSV and transform it into a hierarchical structure suitable
// for a partition layout. The first column is a sequence of step names, from
// root to leaf, separated by hyphens. The second column is a count of how
// often that sequence occurred.
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {"name": "root", "children": []};
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    var sequence = csv[i][0];
    var size = +csv[i][1];
    if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
      continue;
    }
    var parts = sequence.split("-");
    var currentNode = root;
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      var children = currentNode["children"];
      var nodeName = parts[j];
      var childNode;
      if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
   // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
    var foundChild = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
      if (children[k]["name"] == nodeName) {
        childNode = children[k];
        foundChild = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
    if (!foundChild) {
      childNode = {"name": nodeName, "children": []};
      children.push(childNode);
    }
    currentNode = childNode;
      } else {
    // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
    childNode = {"name": nodeName, "size": size};
    children.push(childNode);
      }
    }
  }
  return root;
};
```

As you can see the raw text commented works fine. But loading the mypizza.csv external file which has the same structure doesn't work.

Here is the link to [mypizza.csv](http://cdn.mrc.gm/figures/mypizza.csv) file.

I am so new to all these and I hope someone out there can help me do this.

Thanks

FP

Comment: it seems to me that something with the text/csv is off. The quoted variable `text` uses a dash (-) as separator, whereas you have commas in the csv. Thus, in the `buildHierarchy` function, you might be using the wrong indices (or split on dash, etc). I guess you might want to check that...

Comment: Hi, I have tried almost all your suggestions and others' but I dont' seem to make any headway. Could anybody else help with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my comment above, I adjusted the `buildHierarchy` function as follows:

```
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {
      "name": "root",
          "children": []
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
      var sequence = csv[i]; //[0];
      var size = +csv[i][0];

      if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
          continue;
      }
      var parts = sequence; //.split("-");
etc....
```

As you can see, in your code you don't have to split anymore, as the values that enter the function are already split up. So I also adjusted the `sequence` and `size` vars to the corresponding values (maybe the wrong ones, but it works, for the sake of the example).

In your case, the `size` was always a `NaN`, so not much was happening

You might want to play around with the values and bring everything in order the way you need it.

You can find the result here: 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chroth/jjf8e6pq/2/)

**NOTE**: I just adjusted the code to display the sunburst, but I didn't have the time to set everything up (breadcrumbs, etc.). I am sure you'll find your way!

Good luck.

Comment: This is awesome. Works like a charm and I am already enjoying it. I have some tidying to do but overall the code works. Thanks.

Comment: I have managed to put everything together that for your valuable help @Pinguin. However, I am now havng to deal with issues relating IE, atleast version 9. I have not tested on later versions. Here is the link to the final [link](http://www.mrc.gm/KPI). My indicators in the Q1, Q2 ... are not showing up as expected. When you hover over each color of red or green, it should indicate targets on the right. This works fine on other browsers but not IE 9 atleast.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help with IE related issues, as I only have OS X here... sorry & good luck!